# Facing code change issue while migrating from es2 to ES7

Tags: elasticsearch

```
public class OrderItemCountsAggregationBuilder {

  public AggregationBuilder getBuilder(Set<OrderItemState> orderItemStates) {

    ImmutableMap<OrderItemState, QueryBuilder> clientStateMap = getClientStateMap();

    FiltersAggregationBuilder stateCounts = AggregationBuilders.filters("stateCounts");

    orderItemStates.stream()
        .filter(x -> !clientStateMap.containsKey(x))
        .forEach(x -> stateCounts.filter(x.name(), termQuery("units.state", x)));

    orderItemStates.stream()
        .filter(x -> clientStateMap.containsKey(x))
        .forEach(x -> stateCounts.filter(x.name(), clientStateMap.get(x)));

    return stateCounts;
  }
}
```

The above code is of ES2 but it is not working current ES7 version.

Can you help me to convert the code from ES2 to ES7?

As ES7 don't have this import,
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filters.FiltersAggregationBuilder;

also the stateCounts.filter will not work with ES7?

How we can do the changes?